# Install options in requirements.in

Tags: python, pip, requirements.txt

I use requirements.in file that I compile to generate requirements.txt

```
pip-compile requirements.in
pip-sync requirements.txt
```

I can specify installation options in `requirements.txt` with

```
--install-options='...'
```

But if I specify the same in a `requirements.in`, I get a syntax error. How do I specify install options in a `requirements.in` file